# Python 3.4: lambda function using a list

Tags: python, lambda

```
list1 = [2,4,5,6,7,89]
lambdafunction = lambda x: x > 20
print(any(lambdafunction(list1)))
```

I basically want it to print true or false on the condition x > 20 if any of the numbers in the list are greater than 20.  How would I do that using an 'any' function and a lambda?  I know how to check for a specific position in the list, but not how to check the whole list.

Comment: Why do you want to use a lambda? It's not needed here..

Comment: Just for a class, we're suppose to practice lambda functions in a few different forms.   A regular function would make more sense here though.

Comment: Actually just using a generator expression makes the most sense.. 
```any(x>20 for x in list1)```

Comment: cool!  yeah that does make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

To keep it functional you could use `map`:

```
list1 = [2,4,5,6,7,89]
lambdafunction = lambda x: x > 20
print(any(map(lambdafunction, list1)))
```

`map` returns an *iterator* in python3 so the values will be lazily evaluated. If the first element in your lists is > 20, not more values will be consumed from the iterator.

```
In [1]: list1 = [25,4,5,6,7,89]

In [2]: lambdafunction = lambda x: x > 20

In [3]: it = map(lambdafunction, list1)

In [4]: any(it) 
Out[4]: True

In [5]: list(it)
Out[5]: [False, False, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
>>> print(any(lambdafunction(x) for x in list1))
True
```

Or even:

```
>>> print(any(x > 20 for x in list1))
True
```

This iterates over the elements of the list and it checks that each element is greater than 20. The `any()` function takes care of returning the correct answer. In your solution you're not iterating over each element.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
list1 = [2,4,5,6,7,89]
lambdafunction = lambda x: [item > 20 for item in x]
print(any(lambdafunction(list1)))
```

`lambdafunction` would return an array of booleans which would be if each element in the array is greater than 20. Then, you could use `any` to see if any of them are true.

But I would recommend using a regular function (using `def`) if possible.

Comment: You should use `lambdafunction = lambda x: (item > 20 for item in x)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function.

```
print(any(filter(lambdafunction, list1)))
```